# Sync Facebook Events in Google Calendar programmatically in Android

Tags: facebook

How to **Import Facebook Events in Google Calendar** using Android, I have made an app in which i am *fetching list of facebook friends with their name, profile pic and birthdays*, but now **i want to show all upcoming facebook events in Google Calendar**...

Please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer: install the Facebook application

If you want to do it programmatically or you want to be able to view the events on your web calendar, you need to push the Facebook events onto your Google Calendar using the Google Calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/